# Does UIImage Cache the File or the Rendered Bitmap?

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiimageview

I generally use Fireworks PNGs (with different layers, some hidden, etc.) in my iOS projects (loaded into NIBs in `UIImageView` instances). Often, I take the PNG and resave it as PNG-32 to make the file smaller, but I'm questioning this now (because then I have to store the Fireworks PNG separately)....

In my cursory tests, a smaller file size does NOT affect the resultant memory use. **Is there a relationship, or is it the final rendered bitmap that matters?**

**Note:** I'm not asking about using an image that is too big in pixels. A valid comparison would be a high-quality jpeg that weights 1mb vs. a low-quality jpeg of the same content that weights 100K. Is the memory use the same?

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageView` does not do any processing so if you set a large image the whole thing is loaded into memory when the imageView needs it regardless of the size of the imageView. So, yes, it does make a difference. You should store the smallest images that work within the `imageView`.

While your current example is using NIB's, if you were creating an app that displays large images acquired from other sources (e.g. the device camera or an external service) then you would scale those to a display size before using them in a `UIImageView`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about file size not image size nor display size here. Is the answer still relevant? Thanks.

Comment: My answer is relevant wrt in-memory size. If the files end up having the same memory footprint then it wouldn't matter which you use. The smaller file size should load a bit faster but that's likely not noticeable. In general, I always recommend use the smallest size resource that works. It's reasonable to factor in other constraints (i.e. your time, etc).

Comment: That's really the question. Is it the resultant bitmap (in full-size) that determines the memory footprint, or the file that must be parsed? What does UIImage cache? Rendered bitmap or the file? Etc. etc. Load times don't matter (much) for this question, unless UIImage is loading from the file each time. JUST modified question to reflect this simpler concern. Thanks again.

Comment: The resultant bitmap is what determines the memory footprint. The file size does correlate to this, e.g. smaller is better and will make a difference. You should see this in instruments once the data has been loaded (e.g. the `imageView` is displayed).